# Opening an Unsupprted File in a Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I open an unsupported file in Notepad++ program and see the random characters, are the random characters the `encrypted` characters of the original file or what are they? What do they represent?

Edit: Question got answered successfully.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The random characters are binary data trying to be displayed as text. Questions asked at SO should usually contain code and what you have tried and what's not working. As it stands, your question is too broad so I'm voting to close it. You may want to ask it at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ which is for more open ended questions like yours.

Comment: To get started with reverse engineering a file, you should generate the smallest file you can, and try to make sense of the binary data using a binary file viewer like http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor Then you create more complex files and check that your findings are true or not and adjust your findings accordingly

Comment: Why do you want to close it? This is a website where we can ask questions, isn't it?

Comment: You cannot ask any kind of question, your question is "too broad" which is one of the reasons that a question can be closed. Check out the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . I did point you to another website where your question would make more sense. I'm not being mean, ask it there http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ and you'll be much more likely to get an answer. However, I did give you some steps in my earlier comments on how to reverse engineer a file.

Comment: I see, well thank you for your advice. I'll dig into that. Now you can do whatever you see right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random characters are symbols that represent the binary contents of the file. The symbol that you see depend on the encoding that you use. For example, if you make a .txt file and write letters into it, what you see on the screen are symbols that represent the bits (zeroes and ones) that are really written in the file. In the case of the .txt file, the encoding used is ASCII. ASCII interprets sets of 8 bits (bytes) and changes them into a symbol that you see on the screen. For example, when you write the letter A, what's really written in the file is the number 65 in binary: 01000001

But Notepad++ supports many different encodings. You can switch the encoding in the Encoding toolbar. So when you open a random file, it probably has some data written in bits (0011101001...) that the program, which usually manipulates these files understands (like image viewers for image files and media players for music files), but they are not letters and words, that's why you get weird symbols, because Notepad++ is trying to interpret those bits as letters.

I hope that makes it a little bit more clear, if not, do ask for further specifics.

Comment: Ok, then I just need to do some thinking here before I ask you a question related to my post..

Comment: I am working on an HMI (Human-Machine Interface) application. The screens that you develop in the software are saved in a file with an extension of .win I am trying to open the .win file and understand how information is organized in the file, because I want to automate my work. I want to write a code that write HMI code for me.

Comment: I've done it in different platforms, but this one is unique. I can't see the information in the .win file. I donno how to read it. That's why I asked my original question..

Comment: What programming language are you using? Why are you trying to read the files? There probably isn't anything to "read". It's likely a bunch of data that only certain programs can interpret.
Also, see this: http://file.org/extension/win

Comment: The programming language is unique to the software. In different platforms, the software allows you to manipulate their files (advanced users do that) so you can manipulate the file and "import it" back to the software with the new changes.

Comment: I can't do it with the current software. However, If I can manipulate the *.win file, then I can automate this process. Btw, the .win file is not Windows system backup files. It sounds similar, but it's not.

Comment: So what is it that you want to achieve here? What's your question?

Comment: My question is: I want to open a .win file, literally read it, and understand how the coding is done in the file. I can copy that knowledge and write a code, outside this software, to automate the HMI development for me.

Comment: @user3700785 If you don't have documentation telling you how the file is organized, you can only reverse engineer it. Reverse engineering a file format is too big a question for SO if you don't know the file format

Comment: For example, instead of creating 10 screens manually and draw a circle in each screen, I want to write a code to create 10 .win files with the circle coding in each file. In this way, I am automating my work. But first, I have to understand how .win file is written.

Comment: The only option you have is to use some kind of software that is capable of interpreting and manipulating this kind of file. The only other option would be to know exactly what every byte in the file stands for and to learn how to read binary code and change it manually (but that's not really an option, to be honest).

The software that can read it is most likely the software that made this file in the first place.

Comment: True that. Like you and Juan said, it is a sort of reverse engineering. I hope these types of questions are not against the policies of this website..

Comment: If I understand correctly you are expecting that there is code in the file.. like computer programming code. Programming code is only there so humans can understand it. Programs don't need it, so you won't file code in there or anything you can understand. Let me give you an example: Let's pretend that I am the computer program. You are using me to make a user interface, let's say you draw a circle. I then save this data for myself in a .win file that I can read. But if it's not going to be code like you wrote it or words or anything a human can read. That would be a waste of space.

Comment: I'm going to write a bunch of numbers and symbols down, because I don't need to remember what the numbers are, like humans do. I just read them one by one and know what they mean, because I'm a machine. Now unless you know exactly the process how this software makes the .win files, you won't be able to interpret it.

Comment: I am sorry, that is not what I meant LOL. I meant more like XML language. I did not phrase my question correctly. Initially, before I found out it was a .win file, I thought it is more like XML file, where the software read the code and interpret that to write a circle, for example, for you when you import it. :)

Comment: Yeah we understood eachother. When I said you are expecting a language XML was included though I know it's not technically a programming language. XML is a human-friendly way for writing things down. It is used only if it is expected for the files to be changed manually, but usually the files that the software manipulates with is gibberish to you and I. And if what you are seeing in notepad++ are weird symbols and not letters and numbers then the file is probably compressed too.

Comment: This software sucks. Not a developer friendly software. But I am determined to figure this out. Thanks for the info,

Comment: Crap! I'll give it a shot. This is a part of my work, but whatever I might solve it, I might not. I'll let you know ;)

Comment: Good luck with that one. You'll need it.

Comment: There was similar issue at my work. Our "senior" engineer thought this was not possible. Guess what happened? He was wrong. I did make a software that automates HMI work for that specific platform and becamse a part of our standards. Good story :)

Comment: I opened the .win file with hex editor program and played with the hex value and accomplished exactly what I was looking for. I just need to experiment with some stuff to make sure I understand the file correctly. However, this is the starting point. Thank you for the help,